# Excel "support": Dynamic chart with multiple selections

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-2013, excel-2016

I have a set of data that I wanna make dynamically by clicking dropdown and to reflect that on chart. The problem is, I have like small tables (like in Example, Material A, B, C..) with their certain columns, and that is always the same. But how to connect them to the chart so that I only click which Material I wanna?

seems simple but I am not figuring out with more selections like this...

[image: Dynamic chart needed]

PivotTables is one of the option, I just managed...but I would like to know with functions also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this problem, actually the best option is Pivot tables. So to put in one sheet all the data (one column for material, other for date and so on..), because theyre in the same shape lets say, and in my case I know I will always get the same shape and set of data, just date/tonnage and registration is gonna be changed. So, hit the refresh button inside Pivot and there you have it.

That looks great using Pivot Charts, without any kind of formulas or functions that gave me a thought at the beginning.

Greets!